# useMemo vs React.memo vs pureComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are many ways to do one thing in react nowadays. Take memo for example, what's the difference between `useMemo` and `memo(MyComponent)` and `React.PureComponent`? Aren't they're doing the same thing? so which one we should use today? If we judge base on the date of the newer API we should use `useMemo`?

Comment: `React.PureComponent` used in `class-based` component, `React.memo` used in the `functional` component, `useMemo` is used for a **lot of computing**, which helps a lot in **program performance**

Comment: @AliYaghoby ok forget about PureComponent, we probably don't need that but how about React.memo and useMemo? they're both can be used at functional component.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `useMemo` and `React.memo` inside the **functional** component

- **React.memo:** Used to memoize components.

Suppose you have **two components**, two of which are on the **same level**, and the **other component is the parent of these** two components. We **pass our states** from the parent component to the children. **When a change is made to one of the child components, the other child component is `re-rendered`**.
React.memo is used to prevent this re-rendering.

[image: Sorry about the painting]

- **React.useMemo:** Used to memoize value

When our **calculations** are allowed in an over function, this function is rendered with **each re-rendering** of the component. Using `useMemo`, we set the `useMemo` to be **re-rendered** only in certain cases

Comment: what's the difference btw useMemo and react.memo?

Comment: @FayChen I explained the same. Read the headlines!!!

Comment: it does the same thing, that's what I understand, you either use useMemo and react.memo

Comment: `React.useMemo` is `useMemo`, `React.memo` is `memo`, what is the problem? I explained both to you. Read **import** docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: no problem, when to not use both? or either? I need use case not same function but different name.